# Neugierige Kollegen bringen ... auf die Palme. (mich oder mir)

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative, learning

I came across a practice question online. Can anyone help explain why the correct answer is mich, and not mir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying verb is *bringen*. Now there are -among others- two version of this verb

> (1) jemandem(Dat.) etwas(Akk.) bringen

> (2) jemanden(Akk.) irgendwohin bringen

(1) is the exchange/transport of goods, e.g.

> Ich bringe *dir* ein Glas Wasser

However, in the above phrase, we find *auf die Palme* which is a specification of *irgendwohin* . Thus it is form (2) and you need the *Akkusativ* form of the personal pronoun. It literally means *to bring (take) someone on top of a palm tree*. Not to be confused with *to bring someone a palm tree*. In the case that would be

> Neugierige Kollegen bringen mir eine Palme.

Comment: I think “to bring someone on top of a palm tree” doesn’t even make sense in English if taken literally. In the sense of (2), it would be “to take someone to the top of a palm tree”. But also that doesn’t fully fit, I think, because German “bringen” also has uses as in “etwas zum kochen bringen”, and I feel like the usage here is similar.

Comment: Still, even when it's a figure of speech, it is bringing someone or something  to some other place.

Comment: @CarstenS, "Jemanden auf die Palme bringen" is colloquial for driving somebody nuts.

Comment: @vonbrand, Danke, das ist mir schon klar ;)

Comment: @planetmaker, except that “to bring” is, afaik, the wrongs verb here. In English, you do not bring someone to the airport, you take them to the airport.

Comment: I think that's why I called it a literal translation. But you're right, take is the appropriate verb.

Comment: Ach so, ich verstehe das jetzt. Danke!

Comment: @Senor Jo in that case, feel free to click on the checkmark left of my answer to mark this as "accepted".

Comment: Carsten, if they are knocked out in the boot of your car, you bring them to the airport :-)